# How to go to another page after login in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-authentication, django-login

I still wonder how to **redirect** after a successful login. At the moment it just redirects me, probably by default, to the **django admin page**. **This is of course not what I want** and I want to get redirected to a custom view with a custom template - to be specific of course the one where I used the **@login_required** decorator. Here are my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from programm.models import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def index(request):
        return render(request, 'index.html')

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def liste(request):
        return render(request, 'liste.html', {'lObj': learningObjective.objects.all()})
```

This is my **login template**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"de-de" }}" >
<head>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}

<div class = "table">
<table>
<tr>
    </td><td><p><u>Login Seite</u></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="/programm/liste.html" /></td>
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="/programm/liste.html" method="post"/>
</form>
</tr>
<table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the **template** which I want to **get redirected to**, which also got the @login_required decorator:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'programm/style.css' %}" />
<div class = "title">
<h1 align = "center">Lernziele</h1>
</div>
</head>

<body>
<div class="liste">
 {% for lObj_ in lObj %}
  <li>Lernziel: {{ lObj_.learningObjectives }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from programm import views
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
        url(r'^liste.html$', views.liste, name = 'liste'),
)
```

The structure looks like this: Projectname _*> Appname(programm) _*> templates _*> index.html, liste.html, registration(direction) _*> login.html

Comment: Show us your login view. You'd probably just need a HttpResponseRedirect instead of a render.

Comment: Okay that will be pretty awkward now for me.. I didn't expect to write my own login view. I always thought when I use the @login_required decorator that a custom template of Django is getting loaded and I can use that one to login. What is the proper way then ?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not to use variable in settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/whatever/page/'
```

Of course, this is if you need always redirects all the people to the same page on every login.